# Factory class with given specs

Tags: java

I've the following requirement for one of the applications that I'm working on in Java.

Have a factory class C, having the following method `create(int src)`, that creates objects of classes `A` and `B`.

The method creates object of class `A`, if `src=1`; object of class `B`,if `src=2`.
Ensure no other class other than `C` can create objects of `A` and `B`.

I cannot use reflection.

This is what I tried till now.

```
class C{

 private int src;

 public c(){
  …//Default constructor
}

public create (int src){

 if(src = 1){
  A aobj = new A();
}
else if (src=2){
 B bobj = new B();
} 

} 

}
```

How can I improve the class defination to make sure its more consistent with original specs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to define a factory class (I suppose you have the [Abstract factory patten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) in mind) is by implementing an interface:

```
public interface IAbstract { }
public class A implements IAbstract { }
public class C implements IAbstract { }

// The factory interface that creates concrete implementations of IAbstract.
public interface IAbstractFactory {
    public IAbstract create();
}

public class AFactory implements IAbstractFactory {
    public IAbstract create() {
        return new A();
    }
} 

public class BFactory implements IAbstractFactory {
    public IAbstract create() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

The factory implementation to use is chosen based on some application configuration. That means, the condition you have in your factory class will move to a higher-level in code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int src = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    IAbstractFactory factory = null;
    if (src == 1)
        factory = new AFactory();
    else if (src == 2)
        factory = new BFactory();
    IAbstract obj = factory.create();
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Are you missing 'public class B implements IAbstract(){ }' ??